# .Net C# Program writable folder only to a specified set of processes

Tags: .net, permissions

How can i set a folder to be writable only to a set of process that are launched by the same master process ?

edited:

My goal is to have a program wich controls a folder (and subfolders) . Only he can , write or alter the content of that folder. The user will have acess to those contents but he cannot alter them ( he can view, execute) .

Comment: Windows security is user based rather than process based and thus your design will be very hard to achieve. How about you tell us what your real problem is and see if we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in .NET library that will accomplish what you're after. One challenge to overcome is that (assuming you're on NTFS, there are no process-level file/folder permissions, there are only ACLs which are user/group level.)

One way you might achieve this would be to create an exclusive lock on the directory (ShareMode = None). Then to allow other processes to create handles to that directory they will need to be child processes which inherit parent handles. Doable, but not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Isolated Storage.  You can set different scopes App Domain, Assembly, etc that the storage is accessible by.

[IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx)

[MSDN Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)